# moodle frontpage show categories list as button

Tags: php, moodle

I need to change my theme to show the categories list on frontpage as buttons like this image instend of show only a simple categories list:

[image]

Which file I need to edit? Where can I find documentation about this? I just searche google but I did not find nothing about

Answer (score 0):

There isn't standard functionality for this.

Here is an overview though.

First you will need to create a central region for displaying blocks, some instructions here

[How to add a block to the center of a page in Moodle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741955/how-to-add-a-block-to-the-center-of-a-page-in-moodle/23741956#23741956)

Then create your own block with the layout you want. Follow the instructions here

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks

Then once installed, add your new block to the frontpage and move it to the central region.